# How can I convert an online image path into base64 without using an async Function?

Tags: image, flutter, base64

How can I convert an online image path into base64 without using an async Function?

```
var base64String = onlinePath.toBase64().toString();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import 'dart:convert' as convert;

class Utils {
  // encode string to base64
  static String base64Encode(String data) {
    var content = convert.utf8.encode(data);
    var digest = convert.base64Encode(content);
    return digest;
  }
}
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.